# Move application windows on desktop programmatically in Gnome or KDE

Tags: c++, gnome, kde-plasma

I want to reposition a application window on the desktop using a c++ program . 
How should i go about doing that , i need solution for both situations .

1. When i have the source of the application which want to move .
2. Move windows of other application by Writing an external program.

Comment: You mean the windows of other applications? I doubt there's a standard way. The relevant specs (EWMH, ICCCM, NET) control how a client communicates with the window manager, but not how it can influence other clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External Bash script:

```
xdotool   search --onlyvisible --class dolphin   windowmove 13 37
#                                         ^                 ^   ^
#                                   window class            X & Y coordinates
```

For more information about this, use `xdotool search`, `xdotool windowmove` and `man xdotool`.

C++ example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string cls="dolphin";
    int x=13, y=37;

    stringstream s;
    s<<"xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "<<cls<<" windowmove "<<x<<" "<<y;

    system(s.str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

And bare minimum example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("xdotool search --onlyvisible --class dolphin windowmove 13 37");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is window class ? how i find the window class for the application i want to move ?

Comment: @rajat I think it should be the same as process name. You don't have to use these classes, look at `xdotool search` information.

Comment: @rajat I've just added that to the answer.