# How to distinguish HSV color of an RGB led in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, mouse, led, hsv

I want to make a program that tracks the position of a pen with a led, moves the mouse and clicks. To do it, I'm using a rgb led and opencv with c++. However, for any of the 3 colors I just get hsv 87,9,255. How do I distinguish them?

Comment: HSV is another way of presenting colors. Bright primary colors should have the H (87) varying more than the other two values, but you seem to have another issue here...

Comment: Would using bgr colorspace be better? The code I used to get the values is here [link to the blog, code in python](http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/hsv-pixel-values-in-opencv/)

Comment: If you just have the 3 colors, yes, I would definitely stick with the RGB values; you can simply get the highest value channel to identify the color directly, instead of trying to evaluate if the color is within a certain Hue range. But as I said, I am not sure your issue is in the color space or even with the color conversion, but probably more with getting the color of the pen in your image... What are the values you get in the RGB color space? Does it make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to convert hsv colour space if you are doing colour based segmentation, as it doesn’t affect the brightness and light variation,

You could use the color range like

```
    cvtColor(src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    inRange(hsv,Scalar(0,50,40), Scalar(10,255,255),thr1); //upper red range of hue cylinder
    inRange(hsv,Scalar(165,50,40), Scalar(179,255,255),thr2);// lower red range of hue cylinder
    thr1+=thr2; // Red pixels.
```

Also see the colour hsv-wheel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299624/human-skin-detecting-with-opencv/22300024#22300024) which will help you to get exact colour range in hsv for a particular colour

Comment: Thanks ;). I think I found a solution to the color matter at least, I just tried using black plastic as background.Now I'm getting different values to each led color.

Comment: About setting the mouse pointer position and click, could you help me with the code? I'm using linux.

Comment: @Vitorbnc See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140880/drawing-rectangle-or-line-using-mouse-events-in-open-cv-using-python

Comment: But this code is for handling mouse events, what I want to do is like a fake mouse input.

Comment: Found the code here!(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109766/move-application-windows-on-desktop-programmatically-in-gnome-or-kde)