# Move Window behind Icons on GNOME (Python)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, x11, gnome

My Mission is to move a Window behind the Desktop Icons on Ubuntu (Which uses GNOME). The Problem? 1. I dont know how and 2. i have to do this in Python. I already heared about Xlib but i dont have any Ideas how to start or what i have to do. I already found 2 Questions here but 1 has no Good Answers and the Second ...

[Move application windows on desktop programmatically in Gnome or KDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109766/move-application-windows-on-desktop-programmatically-in-gnome-or-kde)

I dont understand the Answer. Hope you know an Answer, thank you!

Comment: Are you even sure that you're not running on Wayland? Please start by taking a look at the existing APIs, so that you get an overview of what is possible. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The link you have provided tells how to change the position (X,Y coords) of the window. But now how to which one to bring front.  Look like this uses a already existing API calls or some interface to the desktop environment. If the GNOME or KDE doesn't have a feature to move windows behind icons, You can't do that with python (or any other lang) with calling API calls. You have to modifie (write new derivative) the desktop environment (GNOME , KDE) by yourself. Which is very heavy work.

Comment: Why would you *want* to "move a Window behind the Desktop Icons"? Wouldn't that look terrible and be confusing?

Comment: No. I play a Video as WebView in this Window. It's an Animated Wallpaper.

Comment: If it's an animated wallpaper that you want to do, then you should say so instead of assuming that the animation will be in a window and generically asking about windows. See the question on the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem